# OnClick Listner of images in Grid View Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a Grid View that have 4 images .So i want to identify which image has been clicked so that corresponding to that i  can start a new activity .

So please help me how can i get this

I have tried this

```
dataView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution

```
dataView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        links[arg2], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

getView can be used for this purpose.for this in getView find View and apply onClicklistner their.to make all views clickable you need to setFocusable(false) on all focusable views.

Answer (score 0):

int arg2 in the OnItemClick method specifies the position.Using that you can get the item clicked.